# to extract pattern from a variable in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a pattern  for example

```
type=hello(10,1)
```

How can I extract text alone into one variable and the contents into another variable in shell script.

The desired output is

```
text=hello
p1=10
p2=1
```

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk with -F to define delimiter

In this case your delimeter can be [=(,]  (escape the open bracket)

```
$ y=$(echo "type=hello(10,1)" | awk -F [=\(,] '{print $2}')

$ echo $y

hello
```

awk index starts from 1, so $2 = hello, $3 = 10, $4=1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash`, you can use a regular expression with capture groups. A simple example:

```
[[ $type =~ (.*)\((.*),(.*)\) ]]
text=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
p1=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
p2=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```

If you are a using a shell that does not directly support regular expression matching, you can use the `expr` command, but it only supports one capture group at a time.

```
$ text=$( expr "$type" : '\(.*\)(' )
$ p1=$( expr "$type" : '.*(\(.*\),' )
$ pt2=$( expr "$type" : '.*(.*,\(.*\))' )
```